# Corrupted .dll file

Tags: dll, runtime-error, mingw, miniupnpc

I am trying to run an application on Windows 10. I built it from source using miniupnpc as a dependency.

However, whenever I run it I get a "missing msys-miniupnpc-17.dll" error. Does anyone know where I could find that file? Or a replacement of it?

I tried renaming the dll I used to compile with and that failed. Then I tried to rename a dll that comes with the miniupnp Windows executable download from their website and it just said "program failed to start correctly".

What is really weird is that I built it against the static `.a` form of minupnpc.

Edit: It turns out msys-miniupnpc-17.dll is a real file! It was in the output of my build when I built my binary. Now it just says that it wasn't meant to be run on Windows if that rings any bells.

Comment: So what is the problem now, after you found msys-miniupnpc-17.dll? What exactly is the error message?

Comment: `msys-miniupnpc-17.dll is either not designed to run on Windows or contains an error. Try installing the program again using the original installation media or contact your system administrator or the software vendor for support`  Which is really odd because I built it from source on Windows using the latest stable release.

Comment: Maybe add more tags like mingw, dll and runtime-error so people following those see your question. Also you could try cygwin if it gives other results. Maybe you can draw clues for compile options from the [various](https://github.com/miniupnp/miniupnp/tree/master/.github/workflows) [CI](https://github.com/miniupnp/miniupnp/blob/master/.travis.yml) [configs](https://github.com/miniupnp/miniupnp/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml) of the project.

Comment: Added more tags. I will look at those thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it seems to be a combination of things. I think I figured it out though.

You need to build with

`cmake -G MinGW Makefiles . && mingw32-make`

and then link with the flag

`-liphlpapi`